# How migration from dynamoDB to postgress while both old and new system has active users working online?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue, data-migration

I have a scenario where I want to **move my existing DynamoDB database to the postgressDB database**.
I already implemented a new system where I can move data via a glue ETL Job and it is working fine in offline cases.

Since my old and new system has active live users, **how can I do this Database migration in a live online case**? what are the best and most popular approaches to tackling this scenario?

Please share the best usage cases. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is way to vague and broad. Do you want to keep both systems running, and need a two way sync? Is each entry tied to a user and you want the users to be move over by and by? Do you want to move data over while people are working and then switch to the new system? Is the table structure identical?

Comment: yes, we have created a new system, However both systems are running with active users.
the sync will be one way to the new system. each entry is tied to the user and I want to move over. 
The idea is to make the new system fully active soon, in between I don't want to miss any data in the previous system. so move data while people are using live(if we have options availiable) .both the table structure is identical.